# get string array from another delimited string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have a string array like below that contains string followed by delimiter(:) and a number.

```
"string:1"
"string:1"
"string:2"
"string:3"
"string:5"
"string:777"
...
```

i want string array that gets the number from the last delimiter (:)

```
"1"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"5"
"777"
```

**I was wanting to know if i can do this with one liner linq** vs having to do a split of each string array and reconstruct a new array by looping through the parent string array.

Comment: Your strings are always `string:XXX` pattern? What other patters they can have?

Comment: no they are not string:XXX pattern

Comment: @gabriel there is `LastIndexOf` already... Generally `Split` provides better *looking* shorter code which is usually the goal of such code-golf questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) along with [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string []arr = {"string:1", "string:1", "string:2"};
string [] result = arr.Select(e=>e.Split(':').Last()).ToArray();
```

To convert it to int array you can use `Convert.ToInt32`

```
int []result1 = arr.Select(e=>Convert.ToInt32(e.Split(':')[1].Last())).ToArray();
```

Comment: " the last delimiter" may mean that there are more than one `:` in the string... `Enumerable.Last` may be better choice

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `string:` part with [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) like;

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "string:1",
    "string:1",
    "string:2",
    "string:3",
    "string:5"
};

var result = list.Select(s => s.Replace("string:", "")).ToArray();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("string:1");
s.Add("string:2");
s.Add("string:4");
s.Add("string:5");
s.ForEach(delegate(String str)
{
   Console.WriteLine( str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(":")));
});
```